# add <li></li> inside <ul> dynamically which contains <img> tag inside <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

After ul tag i want to call function in javascript to add list item dynamically 
and inside i want to place image tag as shown below.

```
<li> <img src="images/testpic" height="200px" width="200px" /> </li>
```

i have used .append() method in jquery but doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                '$('ul').append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' width='175' height='175' /></li>");
                '$('ul').append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' width='175' height='175' /></li>");
                '$('ul').append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' width='175' height='175' /></li>");
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have your tags incomplete at the start and end of your string?

Comment: you have broken html in your code example: `li>` without starting `<`

Comment: It looks like you're missing the beginning `<` and have an extra ending `>`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### From a for loop

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    $("<li>",{ html:'<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100?image='+i+'" />' })
        .appendTo("#images");   
}​
```

#### From an Array of Images

If all you're wanting to do is add list items with images inside:

```
// You have a mention of i in your example, so I assume you are
// cycling over some sort of list - so I'll do the same
​var images = [ 'http://placekitten.com/50/50', 
               'http://placekitten.com/50/50?image=2' ];

// You had some malformed markup in your code, the following keeps it simple
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​$.each( images, function( i, v ) {
    $("<li>", { html: '<img src="' + v + '" />' }).appendTo("#images");        
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YwH7Z/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your image number starts at `0` ...

```
$('ul').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' style='width:175px; height:175px; '/></li>");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yRS9R/)

Assuming it starts at `1`..

```
$('ul').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+(i+1)+".jpg' style='width:175px; height:175px; '/></li>");
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yRS9R/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').each(function() {
   $(this).append("<li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' width='175' height='175'/></li>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

can fix error by the steps below:

1. You sure that using `$('ul')` can find the ul tag element? If not, please put your code in `$(function(){/**put your append code**/})`, and make sure `<body>` contains `<ul>` element.
2. You sure that appended html is formatted? Put "`li><img src='thumbs/image"+i+".jpg' width='175' height='175' /></li>>`" into `<ul>`, then see the li is shown on the browser?